# Using in_array in multidimensional array

Tags: php

Ill just explain by showing my code:

```
if($_POST)
{
for ($records = 1; $records <= $_POST['numberofrecords']; $records++)
    {
    if((!in_array($_POST['user'][$records], $assigned_users, true))||($_POST['user'][$records]==''))    
       {
       $phonePost['user']       = $_POST['user'][$records];
       $phonePost['id']     = $_POST['id'][$records];

       $this->autoprov_model->update_phone_user($phonePost);
       }                        
   else
       {    
       //other actions.....
       }
```

etc....

$assigned_users is a query listing all IDs currently selected.

the relevant html is

```
<select name=user[<?=$lines;?>] style="position: relative; right: 120px;" onchange="submitform(this)">
    <?php if($phone['user_id']=='')echo '<option value="">Unassigned</option>'?>
    <?php foreach ($users_list as $user):?>
    <?php if($user['id']==$phone['user'])$selected = 'selected="selected"'; else $selected = '';?>
    <option value="<?=$user['id'];?>" <?=$selected?>><?=$user['name'];?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Whats happening is that I am posting all kinds of IDs (relevant to the $assigned_user array) but not actually in the array. and also when I post '' (blank) they never get updated and only reach the second section.

I ask here incase I am missing a trick with posting the values as arrays?

Comment: can you show how you formed the html of `user` input element?

Comment: also, what is in `$assigned_users`?

Comment: or just do a `var_dump($_POST['user'])`

Comment: why did you start the loop with `$records = 1`?

Comment: the data/ form info is generated by foreach and is independently modified in a table so needed a way to add ids front end and back end

Comment: normally, it would start from `0` as that is how an Array is.

Comment: personal preference/making the arrayed posts synchronised really...

Comment: so it means `$lines` also starts with `1`, right?

Comment: $lines starts with 0, however the $lines++ is before $lines is called anywhere relevant to this scenario.

Comment: @MrSorbose : Have you seen / read my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should put name in quotes in your select tag. Like this: `name="user[<?=$lines;?>]"`.
2. `$assigned_users` should be an array.
3. check existence with `isset($_POST['user'][$records])` instead of comparing it with empty string, or simply try this: `if((@in_array($_POST['user'][$records], $assigned_users, true)==false){`.

Comment: 2. What makes you think its not?

Comment: 3. No. No. **No**. Never. ever. use. `@` to. suppress. errors.

Comment: As an *experienced web engineering* are you seriously saying *yes* to the suppression of errors in PHP?

Comment: why are you so obsessed in forcing your opinion !! let it go and find something else to do on stack !!